# Do Iphone Apps have a Cache?

Tags: iphone, caching

I am just trying to figure out some memory confusion with my App.  Do iphone apps have a cache that store images and such?  My memory jumps up when I switch screens, but doesn't go back down when I switch back to the previous screen.

Comment: My leaky sense is tingling...

Comment: Are you releasing all objects that you're allocating? (Or just using ARC for that matter?)

Comment: If you are using `[UIImage imageNamed:]`, it will cache the image in memory.

Comment: Yep, i'm using [UIImage imageNamed:].  Hmm.  I'm also using ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This makes sense, especially for apps with lots of images, because you wouldn't want to be fetching those resources from memory every time a user loaded a view. This is true for dynamically-loaded content as well, which is why apps like Flipboard hog a ton of memory :P

If you're worried about it, just make sure to be more aggressive with releasing resources that are rarely used, for example view-specific images. Other things like background images, which may be on every view, should be kept around in cache.

Comment: Being "more aggressive with releasing images" will not result in recovering memory if he used `imageNamed` because even if you release the images, they'll remain in the cache.

Answer (score 2):

The `imageNamed` method caches the image, but the cache is purged under memory pressure, so if you're confident that your view controller is being released, then you might not worry about it. If it's an image you don't want cached, use `imageWithContentsOfFile` and it won't cache. According to the `imageNamed` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW10):

> If you have an image file that will only be displayed once and wish to ensure that it does not get added to the system’s cache, you should instead create your image using [`imageWithContentsOfFile:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW12). This will keep your single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially improving the memory use characteristics of your app.